# Is there any equivalent for the wear RemoteInput.setChoices, but for the phone?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

What I would like to achieve is quite simple to explain:
I want the user to pick an item by voice from a list and get the result in the app, exactly like the RemoteInput.setChoices (Which is unfortunately made for watch only).

Below is the code need to speak to the watch, but I would like to achieve this feature on a phone.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: You have certainly looked into Android's [speech to text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) API. Is implementing your own UI item based on this an option?

Comment: Of course I looked at it. Main problem is not the UI, it's the recognition itself that can be greatly improved by giving a list of choices. This feature is really on Google side, I am convinced.

Comment: Re: Quality - I'd give it a try. Shouldn't the recognizer deliver a *list* of recognition candidates, which you could then match against your valid words to find the best match within your set? If I said "maybe" and google thinks I most probably said "grey tea" that's of no use, but I'd expect "maybe" to appear somewhere in the list of candidate words, while "yes" and "no" shouldn't be in the list at all.

Comment: I think that's the solution I9 will use, I am so disapointed that a feature that already exists, is completely accurate, and easy to use cannot be reused on the phone... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the method is also available in phone also., since it is not specified in the api guide and the method setChoises() belongs to the class `android.support.v4.app.RemoteInput.Builder`.